# How do I make sure my external process creates a new file instead of overwriting it?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Below is the code I used to write the file on my destination folder, howerver by some logic if same file I want to create having some different data into it, it gets overwritten on that location.

My requirement is not to overwrite the file but keep the old file as it is and creating new file having similar name but by just appending next copy to it, for example `my_file.pdf(1)` or something like that

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
string switches = "";
switches += "--header-html " + path + " --footer-html " + footerPath;// + " --header-spacing 10";
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
startInfo.FileName = Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["wkhtmltopdfsetup"].ToString());
startInfo.Arguments = switches + " " + website + " " + destinationFile;

Process myProcess = Process.Start(startInfo);
string error = myProcess.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
myProcess.WaitForExit();
myProcess.Close();
myProcess.Dispose();
myProcess = null;
```

Comment: Why don't you add a datetime stamp to the original file?

Comment: you need to create a function that check if the file already exists

Comment: to check if the file exists you may use the following code `using System.IO;
if (File.Exists(path)) 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("file exists");
                }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like

```
//Save file if one does not exist
if (!File.Exists("Your File"))
{
   //Save file code here
}

//if file exist then add a datetime stamp to the file name so it does not overwrite the old one
else
{
  string newFileName =
  Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName("path of the file"),
  string.Concat(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension("your file"), 
  DateTime.Now.ToString("_yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss"), 
  Path.GetExtension("your file")));
  //Save new file code here
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could start by comparing the existing file's size to the new one. If they differ, the files are different. Comparing ends here and you do not need to go further (using more process time). If they do not, they might be the same but we cannot be quite sure. Depending on the way files may differ, you could just compare a chunk of the files content. If the differences are very small or exclusivelly at the end or the begining of the document, compare accordingly. Worse case senario, you will have to compare the whole file.